# How do I split image into pieces

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am looking at a way to divide the image into pieces.

The no of pieces that the image can be split into is configurable using tile_height and tile_width.Looking for help.

I would not want any solution with any frameworks. Only using vanilla JavaScript

I tried the below

```
var _clipX =0;
var _clipY = _clipX;
var _clipHeight = IMAGE_HEIGHT/TILE_HEIGHT;
var _clipWidth = IMAGE_WIDTH/TILE_WIDTH;
var _nRows = Math.floor(IMAGE_HEIGHT/TILE_HEIGHT);
var _nColumns = Math.floor(IMAGE_WIDTH/TILE_WIDTH); 
for(var i=0;i<_nRows;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<_nColumns;j++){
        el.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, _clipX, _clipY, _clipWidth, _clipHeight, _clipX, _clipY,_clipWidth , _clipHeight);
        _clipX = _clipX + _clipWidth;
    }
    _clipX = 0
    _clipY = _clipY + _clipHeight;
}
```

Below is the JSFiddle for the work

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raviteja_avvari/a0h3j55t/)

Comment: How did that not work, what went wrong?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/raviteja_avvari/rencoy1t/

Comment: what was the result of the above ?

Comment: My expectation is to get back the same image. I am aware that it can be done without passing clipping values but I want them to be separately accessible for some extended work

Comment: Planning to extract the dominant color from every tile

Comment: Is there any problem with using drawImage inside for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Yes!!!

Found it. Instead of iterating over the image tag dimensions when you call draw image it does iterate over the natural dimensions of the image hence the issue I faced.

Now I have tried with the image size same as my img tag dimensions and it works perfectly fine.

Thanks everyone for the help offered